# How to open an html file from textmate directly on the browser?

Tags: textmate

I would like to see the page that I'm working on TextMate to the browser without do that from the finder. Is it possible? Some editors and IDEs like Eclipse and Netbeans do it easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Bundles > HTML > Open Document in Running Browser(s)